# php multidimensional array retrieve the value into jquery

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
"party1" : { 
        "address" : [ 
                    { 
                    "country" : "Malaysia", 
                    "address1" : "AL 1", 
                    "address2" : "AL 2", 
                    "city" : "Chennai", 
                    "zipcode" : "600010", 
                    "state" : "MY.JH" 
                    }, 
                    { 
                    "country" : "Malaysia", 
                    "address1" : "AL 21", 
                    "address2" : "AL 22", 
                    "city" : "Chennai", 
                    "zipcode" : "600012", 
                    "state" : "MY.KH" 
                    } 
                ] 
        }
```

I need to get the address1 value in using jquery.

I tried this in PHP format :

`$y[o]['party1']['address][0]['address1'];` - It's working.

I try this in Jquery :

```
data-prefix = "party1" 
data-fields ="['address][0]['address1'] | ['address]['address1'] | ['address][0].address1 | address.address1 : "Address 1""
```

I'm getting `undefined` error.

Comment: ```['address]``` double-check if you're correctly closing ```'```, also use parenthesis with ternary operator

Comment: `"Address 1""` ???

Comment: Hi thanks for your valuable reply.

Comment: data-prefix="party1" data-fields='{"address[0][address1]":"Address 1","address[0][address2]":"Address 2","address[0][zipcode]":"ZIP code","address[0][city]":"City","address[0][state]":"State",‌​"address[0][country]‌​":"Country}' - ADDRESS 1 FIELD NOT DISPLAYING IN MY MODAL BOX.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 myArray = "party1" : { 
     "address" : [ 
                 { 
                 "country" : "Malaysia", 
                 "address1" : "AL 1", 
                 "address2" : "AL 2", 
                 "city" : "Chennai", 
                 "zipcode" : "600010", 
                 "state" : "MY.JH" 
                 }, 
                 { 
                 "country" : "Malaysia", 
                 "address1" : "AL 21", 
                 "address2" : "AL 22", 
                 "city" : "Chennai", 
                 "zipcode" : "600012", 
                 "state" : "MY.KH" 
                 } 
             ] 
     }

myArray.party1.address.address1
```

Comment: data-prefix="party1" data-fields='{"address[0][address1]":"Address 1","address[0][address2]":"Address 2","address[0][zipcode]":"ZIP code","address[0][city]":"City","address[0][state]":"State",‌​‌​"address[0][countr‌​y]‌​":"Country}' - ADDRESS 1 FIELD NOT DISPLAYING IN MY MODAL BOX.

Answer (score 0):

with jquery:

```
$asd = {"party1" : { 
    "address" : [ 
                { 
                "country" : "Malaysia", 
                "address1" : "AL 1", 
                "address2" : "AL 2", 
                "city" : "Chennai", 
                "zipcode" : "600010", 
                "state" : "MY.JH" 
                }, 
                { 
                "country" : "Malaysia", 
                "address1" : "AL 21", 
                "address2" : "AL 22", 
                "city" : "Chennai", 
                "zipcode" : "600012", 
                "state" : "MY.KH" 
                } 
            ] 
    }}

   alert($asd.party1.address[0]['address1'])
```

Comment: data-prefix="party1" data-fields='{"address[0][address1]":"Address 1","address[0][address2]":"Address 2","address[0][zipcode]":"ZIP code","address[0][city]":"City","address[0][state]":"State",‌​‌​"address[0][countr‌​y]‌​":"Country}' - ADDRESS 1 FIELD NOT DISPLAYING IN MY MODAL BOX.

Answer (score 0):

Just access it like this .

```js
var ss = {"party1" : { "address" : [ { "country" : "Malaysia", "address1" : "AL 1", "address2" : "AL 2", "city" : "Chennai", "zipcode" : "600010", "state" : "MY.JH" }, { "country" : "Malaysia", "address1" : "AL 21", "address2" : "AL 22", "city" : "Chennai", "zipcode" : "600012", "state" : "MY.KH" } ] }};

console.log(ss.party1.address[0]['address1']);
```

Comment: data-prefix="party1" data-fields='{"address[0][address1]":"Address 1","address[0][address2]":"Address 2","address[0][zipcode]":"ZIP code","address[0][city]":"City","address[0][state]":"State","address[0][country]":"Country}'

Comment: How i get address1 value